# Map from base list to another base list using derived types

Tags: inheritance, automapper

I'm trying to map something like the following.

```
public abstract class AnimalBLO { }

public abstract class AnimalDLO { }

public class HumanBLO : AnimalBLO { }

public class HumanDLO : AnimalDLO { }

public class LionBLO : AnimalBLO { }

public class LionDLO : AnimalDLO { }

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<HumanDLO, HumanBLO>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<LionDLO, LionBLO>();

        var dlos = new List<AnimalDLO>()
        {
            new HumanDLO(),
            new LionDLO()
        };

        var result = Mapper.Map<List<AnimalBLO>>(dlos);

    }
}
```

Where the base type for the list is AnimalBLO but they are mapped as the derived type.  Is there a way to do this without casting out all the objects, then unioning them back together?

I thought this code would work:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<AnimalDLO, AnimalBLO>()
            .Include<HumanDLO, HumanBLO>()
            .Include<LionDLO, LionBLO>();

        Mapper.CreateMap<HumanDLO, HumanBLO>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<LionDLO, LionBLO>();
```

However, the following exception message is thrown:

> {"Instances of abstract classes cannot be created."}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 4.2 (and probably 5.X) the solution would look like:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{

    cfg.CreateMap<AnimalDLO, AnimalBLO>()
        .Include<HumanDLO, HumanBLO>()
        .Include<LionDLO, LionBLO>();

    cfg.CreateMap<HumanDLO, HumanBLO>();
    cfg.CreateMap<LionDLO, LionBLO>();
});

var dlos = new List<AnimalDLO>
{
    new LionDLO(),
    new HumanDLO(),
};

var result = config.CreateMapper().Map<List<AnimalBLO>>(dlos);
```

Answer (score 2):

AutoMapper has [Mapping inheritance](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Mapping-inheritance) feature working exactly as you described. I've added `Tag` property to classes to verify which map is called:

```
public abstract class AnimalBLO
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the successful test:

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
        cfg.CreateMap<AnimalDLO, AnimalBLO>()
              .Include<HumanDLO, HumanBLO>()
              .Include<LionDLO, LionBLO>();
        cfg.CreateMap<HumanDLO, HumanBLO>().AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Tag = "mapped as Human");
        cfg.CreateMap<LionDLO, LionBLO>();
    });
}

[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var dlos = new List<AnimalDLO>
    {
        new HumanDLO(),
        new LionDLO()
    };

    var result = Mapper.Map<List<AnimalBLO>>(dlos);
    var human = result.First();

    Assert.IsInstanceOf(typeof(HumanBLO), human);
    Assert.AreEqual("mapped as Human", human.Tag);
}
```

Comment: That looks like EXACTLY what I want, I'll test it tonight and most likely accept!!  Thanks.

Comment: This looks like it works for older versions of AutoMapper (and the current if anyone is ok with warnings about obsolete).